# Docker jenkins container, host key verification failed

Tags: git, jenkins, docker, ssh, configuration

I'm creating a CI pipeline and development environment with Vagrant, Ansible and Docker. My goal is to have everything automated with a single command, no manual configuration involved. With single *ansible-playbook* command I should have fully functional *continuous deployment* pipeline, all the services dockerized.

Now here's the problem. When I run the official Jenkins docker container and try to configure authentication for git, I get the following error

`host key verification failed`

I understand I could login into Jenkins container, ssh to git manually and accept the host key as trusted, when login for the first time. But this is absolute no-no, the connectivity should be handled automatically too.

How do I configure Jenkins docker container to trust the git server at creation, when the available tools are docker, ansible and vagrant?

Comment: Have you setup any ssh authentication method within the jenkins container by generating **ssh key-pair**? If so then jenkins container can connect automatically git server without interacting a password. Besides host key verification is just a matter of client verification problem and can be eliminated by adding git server's host key to the jenkins user's **known_hosts** file.

Answer (score 4):

I'm building something similar with my pipeline stages encapsulated in containers orchestrated by Kubernetes and I'm able to source modules from my private bitbucket server using the ssh-agent Jenkins plug-in inside `hashicorp/terraform:light` image based container via git+ssh seamlessly. I faced the same issue as yours from the `ansible/ansible-runner` image when I tried to download my roles via `ansible-galaxy` from the same bitbucket server.

I tried to do the same as with terraform and ssh-agent

My relevant pipeline snippet looks like this:

```
container('ansible') {
   ...
   sshagent([ssh_key]) {
      ...
      stage('get ansible roles') {
         sh 'ansible-galaxy install -r requirements.yaml -p roles/'
         ...
     }
   }
}
```

It failed and `ansible-galaxy` is actually hiding the problem pretty well:

```
+ ansible-galaxy install -r requirements.yaml -p roles/
 [WARNING]: - ans_rol_test was NOT installed successfully: - command
 /usr/bin/git clone ssh://git@mybitbucketserver.org/project/ans_rol_test.git
 ans_rol_test failed in directory /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-
 106DvbAa0/tmp09xwe_ (rc=128)
 ERROR! - you can use --ignore-errors to skip failed roles and finish processing the list.
```

After I saw this is just a plain git clone, I tried to clone a repository from the pipeline:

```
+ /usr/bin/git clone ssh://git@mybitbucketserver.org/project/ans_rol_test.git
Cloning into 'ans_rol_test'...
Host key verification failed.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Then I tried just ssh into the bitbucket server.

```
+ ssh git@mybitbucketserver.org
Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
Host key verification failed.
```

I realized when I ssh via the `-oStrictHostKeyChecking=no` the host key is saved anyways but the ssh client returns with `255` because of sshd and the pipeline fails so I've put a `|| true` at the end.

```
Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
Warning: Permanently added 'mybitbucketserver.org,10.5.132.51' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
shell request failed on channel 0
+ true
```

After this the host key is 'verified' so `git clone ssh://` works therefore `ansible-galaxy` too.

```
...
stage('get ansible roles') {
    sh 'ssh -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no git@mybitbucketserver.org || true'
    sh 'ansible-galaxy install -r requirements.yaml -p roles/'
    ...
 }
...
```

output:

```
+ ssh -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no git@mybitbucketserver.org
Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
Warning: Permanently added 'mybitbucketserver.org,10.5.132.51' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
shell request failed on channel 0
+ true
[Pipeline] sh
+ /usr/bin/git clone ssh://git@mybitbucketserver.org/project/ans_rol_test.git
Cloning into 'ans_rol_test'...
[Pipeline] sh
+ ansible-galaxy install -r requirements.yaml -p roles/
- extracting ans_rol_test to /home/jenkins/agent/workspace/configuration/roles/ans_rol_test
- ans_rol_test (1.0.0) was installed successfully
```

Worth noting that setting `GIT_SSH_COMMAND` environment variable with

```
"ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no"
```

is not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Ansible's known_hosts](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/known_hosts_module.html) module for solving this problem.

This module adds the host key into the server's `~/.ssh/known_hosts` file, similar to what you describe as a manual step.

Please note the limitations of the module as well:

> If you have a very large number of host keys to manage, you will find the [template](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/template_module.html#template) module more useful.

Comment: It feels paradoxical to configure running docker container with ansible, as docker containers are intended to be complete and independent. Is it possible to provide the key when starting the container, either with pure docker command or ansible docker_container module?